# If the side of a square $X$ is random with the pdf $f_{X}(x)=\frac{x}{8}, x\in (0,4)$, and $Y$ is the area of the square, find the pdf of $Y.$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $Y$ is the area of the square, then I can write $Y$ as a function of $X$ like that: $Y=X^2$.
Now we can use the definition of distribution function: $$F_{Y}(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(X^2\leq y)$$

I tried to do that, but I have some problems.

Comment: You seem to be on the right direction. $\Pr(X^2 \leq y) = \Pr(X \leq \sqrt{y}) = y/16$. Now just find out the possible range of $Y$ and you will have your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_{X}(x)=\frac{x}{8}, x\in (0,4)$

$Y = g(X) = X^2$.

Please note that $X$ is a continuous random variable and $g(X)$ is a strictly increasing function and differentiable on $(0,4)$. So we do not have to find CDF. We can directly find pdf of $Y$ as follows.

$g'(x) = 2x$.

For any $y \in (0,16)$,

$f_Y(y) = \frac{f_X(x)}{|g](x)|} = \frac{x/8}{2x} = \frac{1}{16}$.

Using CDF, $F_Y(y) = F_X(\sqrt y) = \displaystyle \int_0^{\sqrt y} f_X(x)dx = \int_0^{\sqrt y} \frac{x}{8}dx = \frac{y}{16}$.

So, $f_Y(y) = F'_Y(y) = \frac{1}{16}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $P(Y \le y) = P(X^2 \le y)$ is exactly the same as $P(X \le \sqrt{y})$, because $x$ is nonnegative.